# If I have a list of 2 variables in python how to sort them according to there occurrence in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

So the software takes inputs from user
And print them as an array.
If the value doesn't occurr more than once it doesnt print it

```
 # for example I had these inputs by the users
 Z=[(2,40),(1,15),(3,9),(2,12),(1,15),(3,9),(1,15)]        

 # so that output should be
 1 15

 3 9
```

Comment: What did you attempt? Include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of occurence with `collections.Counter` and then use it as key for sorting in decreasing order of number of times an item appears in the list.

```
from collections import Counter

def sort_by_occurence(lst, min_occurence=1):
    counter = Counter(lst)
    occ = (k for k, v in counter.items() if v >= min_occurence)
    return sorted(occ, key=lambda e: counter[e], reverse=True)

z = [(2, 40), (1, 15), (3, 9), (2, 12), (1, 15), (3, 9), (1, 15)]
sort_by_occurence(z, min_occurence=2) # [(1, 15), (3, 9)]
```

Comment: Yeah that was my bad I meant to say that to be sorted and out put to be printed once as in (1,2)  (3,4)

Comment: I don't understand, do you need your element to be sorted from the most common to the least?

Comment: Yeah,. But it has to occur more than once in z

Comment: Ok, then the above code does exactly that.

Comment: And in the output it has to occur once

Comment: Thank for the help man really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) like:

```
from collections import Counter

Z=[(2,40),(1,15),(3,9),(2,12),(1,15),(3,9),(1,15)]
x = Counter(Z)
print ([k for k, v in x.items() if v > 1])
```

#### Results:

```
[(1, 15), (3, 9)]
```

Comment: Can u  print in matrix form

Comment: @MarioSorial, What?  I don't understand.

Comment: As in 1 15 \n 3 9

Comment: By the way thank you so much for giving me time for help

Comment: `print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(s) for s in k) for k, v in x.items() if v > 1))`

Comment: @MarioSorial, you are very welcome.  However, on SO the very best way to say thanks is to upvote *any* questions or answers you find useful.  And on your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer.  See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines.

Comment: I want to point out that this does not sort as required, it will not work in general.

Comment: There was sorting requirement?

Comment: It was in the title, that's why I think you might have missed it in the question and OP might have thought you saw it because your output actually is sorted (a 2-list is always sorted one way or another).